# Facebook SDK no autologin wanted!

Tags: facebook

Im using Facebook's SDK for my site so users can login with their FB account. The problem is that if they are logged into FB and go to my site, the get auto logged in(only if they have accepted to use it on my site.)

Is it possible to make it so they have to press the login button if they want to login?

Comment: well it is YOUR code doing the auto-login (not facebook), so just modify your code to not automatically sign them in. am i missing something?

Comment: The code is standard from the examples, and havent changed it..so it does this as default. Changing the FB.init status: false causes the script to not function(login button dont work)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a behavior derived from a cookie that's persisting. Maybe they're not getting auto-logged in, but rather they *are still* logged in from last time.

I don't know what your code looks like, but try running FB.getLoginStatus() when the page is visited and the authResponse object is not null then there's an active cookie showing the user to be both authorized for the app and currently logged in. You could

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // take whatever action you want
    }
});
```

Facebook lets you ask 'offline' permission from users which would be a cookie that never expires; it sounds like you want one that expires as soon as the user closes their browser and I don't know if FB currently gives us a way to control that, but I don't think so.